# PHP setcookie doesn't work after "echo" on production server (it does work on localhost)

Tags: php, cookies, echo, setcookie

I've got a pretty decent like system for my website. As soon as a user clicks the ❤️ my `script.js` sends an Ajax containing the blog post's pathname to my PHP server which checks whether the user has already liked it (if so, there's a respective cookie). If not, it reads the content of my `like.json` and looks for the count of the post which will then be increased by 1. After that, the server gives the user a cookie saying he's already liked this post.

Now I tell you: Everything works absolutely fine on my localhost. But when I upload everything to the production server, it fails to set the "already liked" cookie.

First, let's see all the code files:

**`script.js` sends the Ajax:**

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'like.php',
    data: { "liked": url },
    success: function(response){
        
    }
});
```

**Here's the PHP file:**

```
<?php

setcookie('why-doesnt-work-anything', 'no-idea', time() + (86400 * 30), NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL);

$url = $_POST['liked'];

$filename = "like.json";
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd, filesize($filename));
fclose ($fd);

$originalcontents = $contents;
$contents = json_decode($contents);
$contents->$url = $contents->$url + 1;

setcookie('nothing-works', 'no-clue', time() + (86400 * 30), NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL);

echo $contents->$url;

setcookie('doesnt-work', 'i-dont-know-why', time() + (86400 * 30), NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL);

$contents = json_encode($contents);

$urls = $url;

if($_COOKIE['like'] != undefined && $_COOKIE['like'] != ''){
    $urls = $url . ',' . $_COOKIE['like'];
}

if(in_array($url,explode(',',$_COOKIE['like']))){
    $urls = $_COOKIE['like'];
    $contents = $originalcontents;
}

setcookie('like', $urls, time() + (86400 * 30), NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL); // the actual liked cookie

$fp = fopen ($filename, "w");
fwrite ($fp,$contents);
fclose ($fp);

?>
```

Here's the "exciting" part: It's not about cookies in general. As you see, I created 3 test cookies. Remember: On my localhost, everything works fine. But on the production server, all attempts to set a cookie fails after the `echo` line. The first 2 cookies work but not the 3rd one.

I don't think it's a bug at my hosting provider (1&1). Is it due to different PHP versions? Or what's the f***ing problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Different configurations. If your local build has output buffering automatically enabled, then you can send headers like `Cookie` whenever you want. But it's a bad idea to be using a cookie to judge whether someone has already liked a thing - cookies can just be cleared and they can "like" it again.

Comment: Its always best (regardless of output buffering on/off) to structure you code to handle all header related things, BEFORE you do any content output related things. Then you don't have to worry if the environment has buffering enabled or not.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, that's right. But since the website hasn't got any register feature there's no option to prevent multiple likes. But who wouldn't want to receive lots and lots of likes... 

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you echo something, you can no more set a cookie unless output buffering is enabled by default in your environment; what might be the case on your localhost.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says:

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

and also:

> **Note:**
> You can use output buffering to send output prior to the call of this function, with the overhead of all of your output to the browser being buffered in the server until you send it. You can do this by calling [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_end_flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) in your script, or setting the output_buffering configuration directive on in your php.ini or server configuration files.

PS: You must also consider the comment of Niet the Dark Absol about using cookie in such a situation.